# Create function of title bar from toolStrip

Tags: c#, statusbar, toolstrip

I'm currently hiding my title bar and had toolstrip on top. Now the toolstrip act as titlebar, but I cannot use titlebar features such as double click to minimize/maximize, drag . How to make toolstrip act as titlebar?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you edit your question to include some of the code you already have and possibly a screenshot?  It's not entirely clear what you are doing from your brief description.

Comment: Please refer http://www.functionx.com/vb/controls/statusstrip.htm

Comment: I think you are talking about a title bar rather than a status bar?

Comment: @Robert yea, just made some changed.

Comment: This is a hint: don't so completely change the UI so that your users (including you) don' understand how to use it.